# C program in Linux, signal handlers

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, shortcut

I am trying to understand basic signals concepts so I can write a program that handles every possible signal printing its id on the screen.

I don’t know what means every possible signals. I have read that we can get all signals handled by system using kill -l commands so do I understand it properly that I should write a program that handles all those 64 signals? I’ve also read that some signals can be sent to the process by keyboard shortcuts but How many signals are there that are sent in that way - I managed to find only Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-. So How to send the rest of the signals to program if there are no shortcuts for the rest of the signals? I can’t get over It for whole day long, asking in forum was my last step I took, Not the first one.

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html is a good place to start for Linux signals.

Comment: you can use kill to send any signal